# What does 'AND 1' / 'AND 0' do in a left join on clause

Tags: mysql, sql

here is a snippet of the relevant question

```
LEFT join tbl_ExpenseReportLineItem erli ON erh.ExpenseReportHeaderID = erli.ExpenseReportHeaderID and 1
```

Depending on if it says 'and 1' or 'and 0' I am seeing different results. I can provide more snippet if needed but I was hoping this has a simple generic answer.

EDIT: Answer helped immensely but the actual problem with my sql was the group by was returning rows I didn't want. (removed sql because work related).

Comment: Condition with ``AND 0`` is always false and condition with ``AND 1`` always depends on left part of AND

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1` and `0` are synonymous with `TRUE` and `FALSE` in MySQL.  Therefore the following conditions are identical:

```
erh.ExpenseReportHeaderID = erli.ExpenseReportHeaderID AND 1
erh.ExpenseReportHeaderID = erli.ExpenseReportHeaderID AND TRUE
erh.ExpenseReportHeaderID = erli.ExpenseReportHeaderID
```

And the following conditions are also identical:

```
erh.ExpenseReportHeaderID = erli.ExpenseReportHeaderID AND 0
erh.ExpenseReportHeaderID = erli.ExpenseReportHeaderID AND FALSE
FALSE
```

When you use `1` in your `LEFT JOIN` you will join on the condition

```
erh.ExpenseReportHeaderID = erli.ExpenseReportHeaderID
```

and when you use `0` you will get no matching records from the second table.  Specifically, every record from the `tbl_ExpenseReportHeader` table will appear, however the columns from the `tbl_ExpenseReportLineItem` table will all appear as `NULL`, because the join condition is `FALSE` for every record.

**Update:**

The reason you are getting records back with the join condition

```
ON erh.ExpenseReportHeaderID = erli.ExpenseReportHeaderID AND 0
ON erh.ExpenseReportHeaderID = erli.ExpenseReportHeaderID AND FALSE
ON FALSE
```

is because you have a condition in your `WHERE` clause which is evaluating to `TRUE` even though `erli.*` will be `NULL` for every record:

```
WHERE ... erli.StatusExport != 'EXPF' OR erli.ExportDate >= '2315-11-11 00:00:00'
OR erli.ExportDate = '2900-01-01 00:00:00' OR erli.ExportDate is null
```

The key condition here is `erli.ExportDate is null`, which will always evaluate to `TRUE`.  And in MySQL `TRUE OR NULL` evaluates to `TRUE`, so this would potentially allow some records to get through into your result set.

Comment: Thanks, can you clarify a bit on 'no matching records'. I get less results than with 1, but it is the correct result.

Comment: I just updated my explanation.  Please review the syntax behind `LEFT JOIN` if you want more information.

Comment: I feel like I understand but I still don't get the result of my query. If every column is null than how am I using the outer where clause to further filter on the status... if the status is null. Sorry for my confusion.

Comment: Upon closer inspection, I noticed that you have _two_ `LEFT JOIN` criteria, the second being `erli.isParent=0 and erli.StatusApproved='RET'`.  My guess is that this second condition is true for some records, and this is why the `WHERE` clause is not filtering everything out.

Comment: I will make one final update.  After this, you should try to research further on your own.